# Difference between width and device-width in CSS media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference (in simple terms) between height and width and device-width and device-height?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5725838/399317

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`device-width` is the...

> width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#device-width).

The `width`...

> describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer)

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#width).

Answer (score 9):

More than a late answer Hopes it will help Some one

> In CSS media the difference between width and device-width can be a
>   bit muddled, so lets expound on that a bit. **device-width** refers to the
>   **width of the device itself**, in other words, **the screen resolution of
>   the device**. Lets say your screen's resolution is 1440 x 900. This
>   means the screen is 1440 pixels across, so it has a device-width of
>   1440px. Most mobile phones have a device-width of 480px or lower,
>   including the popular iPhone 4 (with device-width: 320px), despite it
>   technically having a 640 x 960 resolution. This is due to iPhone 4's
>   retina display, which crams two device pixels into each CSS pixel on
>   the screen. This is true for the Ipad 3 as well; its reported
>   device-width is 768px just like its predecessors, even though its
>   actual screen resolution is 1536px x 2048px. In general width is more
>   versatile when it comes to creating responsive webpages, though
>   device-width is useful when you wish to specifically target mobile
>   devices (and not desktops with a small browser window for example)

**as from** [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#width) **,**

> **width :**  
>   Value:  Media: visual, tactile 
>   Accepts min/max prefixes: yes
>
> The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface
>   of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the
>   width of the page box on a printer).  
>  
>   **Note: As the user resizes the window browser switches style sheets as appropriate based on media queries using the width and height media features. !!!**

i found this article very interestingly from  javascriptkit :
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Comment: Thanks. This explains the whole topic quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation, it really helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you define `device-width` means your particular css is call when you open your page in iphone, ipad ,ipod & mobile device . for example :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
        body{
          color:red;
        }
    }
```

or if you define width which means your particular css is call when your window is resize .
for example :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        body{
         color:yellow;
        }
    }
```

for more info please check http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries , http://x7.fi/2010/02/12/how-to-fit-your-website-for-the-apple-ipad/

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw width & device-width both apply on mobile devices but when we add "device-width" then the css only apply on the device not on desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a cross-platform app (eg. using phonegap/cordova) then,

Don't use device-width or device-height. Rather use width or height in CSS media queries because Android device will give problems in device-width or device-height. For iOS it works fine. Only android devices doesn't support device-width/device-height.

Answer (score -5):

The `device-width` describes the height of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).

Whereas the `height` CSS property specifies the height of the content area of an element. The content area is inside the padding, border, and margin of the element.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/

For more on media queries, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/