# Difference between aspect-ratio and device-aspect-ratio in CSS media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference in simple terms between `aspect-ratio` and `device-aspect-ratio`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5716066/399317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `aspect-ratio`

> Describes the aspect ratio of the targeted display area of the output device.  This value consists of two positive integers separated by a slash ("/") character.  This represents the number of horizontal pixels over the number of vertical pixels.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#aspect-ratio).

#### `device-aspect-ratio`

> Describes the aspect ratio of the output device.  This value consists of two positive integers separated by a slash ("/") character.  This represents the number of horizontal pixels over the number of vertical pixels.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#device-aspect-ratio).

Comment: but what is the targeted display area for the aspect ration mean?

Comment: @poptag I think `aspect-ratio` to `device-aspect-ratio` is like viewport size to screen resolution.

Comment: so like the browser window for the aspect ration and the entire screen for the device-aspect-ratio?

Answer (score 42):

For everyone who is confused about the difference between **targeted display area** and **output device** regarding the aspect-ratio:

**targeted display area**

> Aspect ratio of your browser window or the area your website is displayed on
>   (a special case would for example be an embedded website)

**output device**

> Physical aspect ratio of the screen. E.g. of your smartphone or desktop display

As smartphones and tablets usually display apps in fullscreen mode only, **aspect-ratio** and **device-aspect-ratio** are the same. On a desktop computer this surely is not always the case as the user can resize the browser window and thus the aspect-ratio changes.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the other just repeats the definitions that were the cause of the initial confusion.

Comment: @PeterHansen How do you know that documentation in the accepted answer was the source of confusion for the OP?

Comment: @alex, good point, I don't. I know it was the source of my confusion (and, clearly, many others, given this answer's vote total). I also think anyone can easily find the definition and read it, so if they had to ask here I assume it was because of that same "target display area" thing. I retract my implication that *everyone's* initial confusion stems from the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

A functional difference on mobile is that having the soft keyboard come up changes aspect-ratio but does not change device-aspect-ratio.

Answer (score 3):

aspect-ratio measures viewport area.
device-aspect-ratio measures device screen area.

Answer (score 2):

**ASPECT RATIO**

The viewport aspect ratio or device aspect ratio is the ratio of the width
to the height. So, if a screen were 1,000 pixels wide and 500 pixels high,
the device-aspect-ratio would be 2:1, because 1,000 is twice 500.
The ratios of screens vary widely, even though at first glance they pretty
much all just look like a similar rectangle.

Common monitor aspect ratios are 16:9 (such as 1920 × 1080 or 1366 ×
768 pixels) or 16:10 (1280 × 800). The iPhone 3 and 4S are 3:2 (480 × 320
and 960 × 640) and the iPhone 5 is 16:9 (1136 × 640). Android phones
are commonly 4:3, 3:2, 16:10, or 16:9.

Examples:

```
@media only screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
{ ... }
@media only screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio:
1920/1080) { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't attempt to explain the difference between the two terms mentioned in the question.