# IPHONE 4 and IPHONE 5 media queries on bootstrap

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

need some help. I created a webpage in bootstrap. My problem was in media queries for IPHONE 4 and IPHONE 5, they both have 320px on portrait. but when i viewed my form IPHONE 4 and IPHONE 5 don't have the same height. here's my code on media queries at 320px portrait. IPHONE 5 extends the height compare to IPHONE 4. how can i set the height on portrait of IPHONE4 and IPHONE 5 at 320px?

```css
div#rightCol_form.container{
   width:100%;
   height:140%;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

these are the media queries for iphone: 5:

```
/* iphone 5 Retina Display: for portrait */
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation:portrait) {}

/* iPhone 5 Retina Display: for landscape*/
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation:landscape) {}
/* iphone 4*/
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
```

[Media Queries helpful link - iphones](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll try this then i'll get back again if i will succeed with this media queries. by the way, what is the meaning of this "device-aspect-ratio: 40/71"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725838/difference-between-aspect-ratio-and-device-aspect-ratio-in-css-media-queries read more there.

Comment: i tried the code you have given but still read the @media only screen (max-width:320 px) {div#rightCol_form.container{
   width:100%;
   height:140%;
     }                                                                                                             }