# Changing CSS depending on if screen is 16:9, 16:10, or 4:3

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently learning coding at school and I am tasked with making a webpage:

[sendnoods.neocities.org](http://sendnoods.neocities.org)

I've already got all of the main graphics and layout I need for 16:9 resolution and 16:10 resolution, but don't know how to implement a different css with those scales.

I know I can set the max-width using:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { 
/* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
}
```

But is there a way I can more generalize it for 16:9, 16:10 and 4:3 resolutions?

Comment: There are `min-aspect-ratio` and `max-aspect-ratio` operators in [CSS media queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5725838/3029422

Comment: you should optimize the images, the page load time is ~2000 ms

Answer (score 8):

There is `aspect-ratio` which can be used in media queries, for example:

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  ...
}
```

It specifies the width/height ratio of the display area.

"min-" and "max-" prefixes can be used, like `max-aspect-ratio:16/9`

Comment: Thanks for helping, although I didn't get this to work I did manage to find a workaround.

Comment: You could also try `device-aspect-ratio` - same principle, but dependent on the device itself, not on the browser window

Comment: `device-aspect-ratio` is deprecated, as reported here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aspect-ratio` for this.

So for example just use

```
@media (aspect-ratio: 16/9){
    //ur css
}
```