# css3 media query question

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to teach myself css3 media queries, and I want I've confused myself over something small.  I can't figure out the difference between width/height and device-width/device-height.  Is device-width/device-height a css3 property only available to certain cell-phones or smaller computers?  If so, is there an online resource which provides the sizes that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good source for common smartphone and tablet sizes already to go in CSS

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Normal width and height styles can be applied to any element on a page. For example if you want the width of a div tag to be set to 100px that's one method to do it.

To learn more about CSS media queries and how they work a good site to read is here http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

The differences have been explained here: [Difference between width and device-width in CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716066/difference-between-width-and-device-width-in-css-media-queries)

Also you'll find a list of sizes here:
 http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Here for a lot of different devices:
http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

And there's quite a nice diagram about a third if the page down:
http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries